# Vuetify v-tooltip unable to change css

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `v-tooltip` of Vuetify and I want to make minor changes in its CSS like `opacity: 1` and inner `padding: 0`. But I am unable to changes any CSS on it. Can someone help please?

```css
.v-tooltip {
    font-size: 50px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

And this is my vue code:

```
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <a
        v-on="on"
        @mouseover="mouseOver(item)"
        @mouseleave="mouseLeave(item)"
      >{{ item.name }}</a>
    ...continued
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Content is under `.v-tooltip__content`. Also it is set on the element itself, so `important` is required as you already did to override the styling.

```
.v-tooltip__content {
  font-size: 50px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work
Basically I just want to remove its opacity, That's it.

Comment: If you look at the source the opacity is overridden : https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/jObdZOZ

Answer (score 7):

For newer versions of Vuetify, the solution provided by @dreijntjens no longer works. The classes have changed, and the `display`-attribute shouldn't be touched as this is how the tooltip is initially hidden.

Here's CSS to darken the background of the overlay and increasing the font size:

```css
.v-tooltip > .v-overlay__content {
  background-color: rgba(var(--v-theme-surface-variant), 0.9) !important;
  font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: If using scoped style in a vue component, you will need to change `.v-tooltip > .v-overlay__content` to `.v-tooltip :deep(.v-overlay__content)`

Answer (score 3):

- Vue version: ^3.3.4
- Vuetify version: ^3.3.7

The solution that I found worked is to set the `content-class` attribute in the `v-tooltip` template element, then in the `<style scoped>` use a **global** css definition:

In the template:

```html
<v-tooltip
  v-model="showTooltip"
  content-class="custom-tooltip"
  ... <!-- other attributes.. -->
>
...
</v-tooltip>
```

In the scoped style:

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
:global(.custom-tooltip) {
  font-size: 0.625rem !important;
  opacity: 1 !important; // This did not set the opacity to 100% opaque
  background-color: rgba(var(--v-theme-surface-variant), 1) !important; // This made the tooltip opacity fully opaque
  padding: 0.1rem 0.3rem !important;
  transform: translate(-0.7rem -0.8rem);
}
</style>
```